# button animation on click then executing the code behind

Tags: wpf, animation, button

I have a button which it opens a new window in XAML. I introduced succesfully a storyboard which animates the button make it turn on button click but the thing is when I applied to make it open a new window it stop it doesn't execute the story it just opens a new window and when I remove the code on button click to open a new window it animates just fine. What I need is to make it execute the animation first i.e the storyboard on button click and then open a new window.

Kindly help,
Best regards,

in Xaml.app

```
<Application x:Class="Shopping_Mall_Test_Project.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <GradientStopCollection x:Key="MyGlassGradientStopsResource">
        <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0.2" />
        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.4" />
        <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.75" />
        <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0.9" />
        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
    </GradientStopCollection>


    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyGlassBrushResource"  

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GrayBlueGradientBrush" 
StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#CCCCFF" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" Opacity="0.75"  


GradientStops="{StaticResource MyGlassGradientStopsResource}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayBlueGradientBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" ClipToBounds="True">

                        <!-- Outer Rectangle with rounded corners. -->
                        <Rectangle x:Name="outerRectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
  RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" StrokeThickness="5" Fill="Transparent" />

                        <!-- Inner Rectangle with rounded corners. -->
                        <Rectangle x:Name="innerRectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Transparent" 
    StrokeThickness="20" 
    Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" 
  />

                        <!-- Glass Rectangle -->
                        <Rectangle x:Name="glassCube" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Opacity="0"
    Fill="{StaticResource MyGlassBrushResource}"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="LightBlue" />
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Gray" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Stroke>

                            <!-- These transforms have no effect as they 
         are declared here. 
         The reason the transforms are included is to be targets 
         for animation (see later). -->
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>

                            <!-- A BevelBitmapEffect is applied to give the button a 
           "Beveled" look. -->
                            <Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                                <BevelBitmapEffect />
                            </Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                        </Rectangle>

                        <!-- Present Text of the button. -->
                        <DockPanel Name="myContentPresenterDockPanel">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter" Margin="20" 
      Content="{TemplateBinding  Content}" TextBlock.Foreground="Black" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- Animation fires when button is clicked, causing glass to spin.  -->
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="glassCube"  
      Storyboard.TargetProperty= 
      "(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(RotateTransform.Angle)"  
      By="360" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <!-- Animations that start when mouse enters and leaves button. -->
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="mouseEnterBeginStoryboard">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <!-- This animation makes the glass rectangle shrink in the X direction. -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="glassCube"  
      Storyboard.TargetProperty= 
      "(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" 
      By="-0.1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />

                                        <!-- This animation makes the glass rectangle shrink in the Y direction. -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetName="glassCube"  
      Storyboard.TargetProperty= 
      "(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"  
      By="-0.1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>

                                <!-- Stopping the storyboard sets all animated properties back to default. -->
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="mouseEnterBeginStoryboard" />
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <!-- Set properties when mouse pointer is over the button. -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                            <!-- Below are three property settings that occur when the 
     condition is met (user mouses over button).  -->
                            <!-- Change the color of the outer rectangle when user          mouses over it. -->
                            <Setter Property ="Rectangle.Stroke" TargetName="outerRectangle"
  Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />

                            <!-- Sets the glass opacity to 1, therefore, the          glass "appears" when user mouses over it. -->
                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Opacity" Value="1"       TargetName="glassCube" />

                            <!-- Makes the text slightly blurry as though you were          looking at it through blurry glass. -->
                            <Setter Property="ContentPresenter.BitmapEffect"       TargetName="myContentPresenter">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="1" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <!-- Set properties when button has focus. -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Opacity" Value="1"       TargetName="glassCube" />
                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" TargetName="outerRectangle" 
  Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Opacity" Value="1" TargetName="glassCube" />
                        </Trigger>



                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

in code:

public MainWindow()
        {

```
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard st = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("glassCube");
        st.Begin();


        Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard st = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("glassCube");
        st.Begin();
        Registration_Form win1 = new Registration_Form();
        win1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }




}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Post the code you tried so far..

Comment: In your code `glassCube` is a `Rectangle`. You can't cast a `Rectangle` to `Storyboard`. How do you expect to see an animation if you close the window right after starting the animation?